# Recovery result of a function via a webservice and stored in a variable

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

I want to get the result of this method : bool  authentication (string log, string pass) and this methode  : string role (string log, string pass) to test authentifcation
this is what I did :

```
private void bntValideAuthen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    client.AuthentificationCompleted += client_AuthentificationCompleted;
    client.RoleCompleted += client_RoleCompleted;

      ServiceConsum.Service1Client client = new ServiceConsum.Service1Client();
     string rol=client.RoleAsync(txtLogin.text,txtpass.text);
     bool auth = client.AuthentificationAsync(txtLogin.text,txtpass.text);


    if((auth==true)&&(role=="admin"))
    {
      NavigationContext.Equals(new Uri("/Views/admin/starAdmin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else
    {
      message.BOX("error");
    }

    }
```

it gives this error :
Can not implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Comment: Looks like your `RoleAsync` and `AuthentificationAsync` methods return `void` type not a `bool` and `string`

Comment: i had developed a wcf , it contains functions :

Comment: [OperationContract]
        public  bool Authentification(string login, string mdp)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          
            var reqLogin = from c in dc.session
                           where (c.login == login && c.passwd == mdp)
                           select c;
            List<session> listuser = reqLogin.ToList<session>();

            if (listuser.Count != 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;


        }

Comment: and i would like to call these function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is :
add a tread in second event like :

```
 void client_RoleCompleted(object sender, RoleCompletedEventArgs e) { 
            role = e.Result.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code starts asynchronous call - it doesn't return string - it is a void method - that's your error.

```
client.RoleAsync(txtLogin.text,txtpass.text)
```

You will get your result as an argument of method client_RoleCompleted. You've subscribed to RoleCompleted event using following code:

```
client.RoleCompleted += client_RoleCompleted
```

Comment: I want to have the results of the two functions to test authentification

Comment: private void client_RoleCompleted(object sender, RoleCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
       
            if (e.Result.Equals("admin") && //authentification == true (HOW !!) ??)
            
           
        }

Comment: [OperationContract]
        public  bool Authentification(string login, string mdp)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          
            var reqLogin = from c in dc.session
                           where (c.login == login && c.passwd == mdp)
                           select c;
            List<session> listuser = reqLogin.ToList<session>();

            if (listuser.Count != 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;


        }

Comment: The simple answer is - store it somewhere e.g. in private fields of this class. You may also call AuthentificationAsync first and call RoleAsync only if it returns true. Then you don't have store intermediate result anywhere.